# Take 1 row of data from MySQL and Split the Results into a Table

Tags: mysql, php, unpivot

I have a mysql database that looks like this:

```
proj_id | job1_name | job1_type | job1_time | job2_name | job2_type | job2_time | ...
--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------| ...
      1 | John      | Roof      |        10 | Jane      | Floor     |         2 | ...
```

Actual table has these three fields (name, type, and time) for up to 5 jobs.

I need the results to display in a table like this:

```
proj_id |  Name  |   Type   | Time
--------+--------+----------+------
      1 | John   | Roof     |   10
      1 | Jane   | Floor    |    2
```

How can I accomplish this?

thanks for all the help!!

Jay

Comment: To clarify - are `job1name`, `'job1_type`, `job1_time`, `job2_name`, etc. all separate columns in your table, or are they a comma-separated list of values stored in a single column in your table? And are there really just two job "slots" per row? Can the second job "slot" be empty? If so, would you not want a row produced for it? What would qualify it as empty - all columns NULL, any 1 column NULL, etc?

Comment: Thanks RDFozz, yes they are all separate columns within the table. There are actually 5 job slots, and only 1 out of five is possible depending on the record. 
I would prefer not to display empty job slots. If any of the fields for that respective job is blank/null then it doesn't need to be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **Union**, you can get the results as you want. But I'm not sure whether it is a good solution.

```
SELECT `proj_id`,`job1_name` AS 'Name',`job1_type` AS 'Type',`job1_time` AS 'Time'
FROM `job`
WHERE 1
UNION
SELECT `proj_id`,`job2_name` AS 'Name',`job2_type` AS 'Type',`job2_time` AS 'Time'
FROM `job`
WHERE 1
```

Why you are having 5 jobs data in different fields. You can add job_id for the reference and other fields as common.

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE! The best answers include details to help the OP resolve their problem. This is more of a comment. As you buildup a reputation here, you'll gain the ability to comment on others' questions and answers.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Each RECORD represents a PROJECT.  So each project has 5 potential JOBS associated to it.  At the time, I wasn't thinking properly. I tried your syntax, but it only displays the top select statement and not the 2nd.  So my results are only for 'job1' and nothing for the other jobs.

Comment: This can be resolved by simply putting **alias** in the select statement.

Comment: Check http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=5168cc1a10354129c30668f8bf1c4337 - This is normally called an `UNPIVOT`.

Comment: Thanks you Tamilvanan and Joanolo for your answers!  That worked!